# Integration Visual Paradigm 15.1 into Netbeans 9 failed. on Mac OS 10.14.1Help please

Tags: macos-mojave, visual-paradigm, netbeans-9

Integration Visual Paradigm 15.1 into Netbeans 9,JDK 11.01.1,  on Mac OS Mojave 10.14.1:

according to Netbeans integration in Visual Paradigm,IDE Netbeans worked, but VP is not visible in Netbeans. Not visible in tools nor anywhere else in Netbeans. Can anyone tell me what is wrong and how to fix it?Thanks a lot! Would be very grateful for your help.

Comment: [1] [NetBeans 9 supports JDK 9 and JDK 10, but does not support JDK 11](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/index.html). That may or may not be relevant for your problem, but NetBeans is definitely configured incorrectly. [2] Is Visual Paradigm compatible with JDK 11? [3] I suggest configuring NetBeans 9 to use JDK 10 instead of JDK 11, then try again. [4] If you still have problems after that check the NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**) for any relevant errors, and update your question if appropriate.

Comment: Thanks a lot but for your help but if you go to the oracle website, I cannot download JDK9 nor JDK 10 because it has not been supported anymore so Oracle strongly advises to use  JDK11.  Even I cannot download JDK10 anymore. I cannot find it. I am just a beginner. Any thoughts are very much welcome. Still stuck on this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can download Oracle JDK 10 from here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase10-4425482.html

Answer (score 0):

Visual Paradigm recently had fixed a problem on NetBeans integraton. Please update the software to latest patch build (20181130ap or later) to get the problem fixed. Details about update to latest patch can be found at

https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/articles/update-to-latest-patch.jsp

- Please make sure you have pressed the "Update to latest patch" button on the left hand side of the dialog right after launching the update program